# Commands from history without command number

Tags: grep, history, cut, bash

I am trying to create a function to add to my bash_profile file in order to be able to extract a list of commands from the history grepping a given word and removing the numbers of the commands. The thing is that I can do it directly like this

```
$history | grep tar | cut -c 8-
```

but when I put it into a function in bash_profile with this

```
function hrep() {
    history | grep $1 | cut -c 8-
}
```

It does not take into account the cut command. It prints out the command grepped but it doesn't trim the command numbers.

Do you know what am I missing?
Thanks a lot in advance,
Juanpe.

Comment: I can not reproduce this error with Ubuntu. Enter the following and try again: `bash --norc`

Comment: If I do that I don't have bash_profile loaded and when I load it it closes the bash session. I can run it from the command line but the problem is when I create a function from it. By the way, this is in a local cluster using Scientific Linux 5, I will try in another machine when I have the chance to see if it works.

Comment: This works fine for me when added to my .bashrc

Comment: It seems that there was some configuration stuck in the system somewhere. When I closed the session and I logged back in via ssh the function works properly. Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use a regex than telling cut to remove a specific numbers of characters. Your history could go far more than a thousand lines.

```
hrep() {
    history | grep $1 | sed 's/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//g'
}
```